# Locus of segments of length $n$ which form an $n^\circ$ angle with the $x$-axis

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, locus

So basically, I was wondering what would happen if you take the locus of line segments of length $n$ that make a $n^\circ$ angle with respect to the $x$ axis. I did this, and this is what I got:

[image: Locus]

I was wondering if there is any properties of this shape and if it is well known in any field of study?

Comment: Do you know what polar graphs / polar coordinates are?

Comment: I'm familiar with the complex plane, but not really polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s consider the graph in polar form:
$$r=\frac{180}{\pi}\theta$$
Technically, this is actually the locus of all of the *endpoints* of the line segments in your diagram. Here’s another picture:

[image]

This shape is called an archimedian spiral. Not sure what kind of properties you find “interesting,” but here are a few:

- The area of the region shaded by line segments in your picture is equal to $15\pi/4$.
- The perimeter of the region in your picture is approximately equal to $209.13$, but its exact length is given by
  $$90+\frac{45\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}{2}+\frac{90\sinh^{-1}(\pi/2)}{\pi}$$
- The graph of this spiral in cartesian coordinates is given by
  $$\frac{\pi x}{180}\tan\Big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big)=y$$

Some interesting applications [can be found here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral)